# Parsing XML: identify / get data for specific element?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following methods in my simple Custom Parser Class, when I execute CALLED: on my data I get ...

```
Found: OK
Found: 046 3433 5674 3422 4456 8990 1200 5284
```

My question is how would I go about adding to this so that I can specifically pick out the information for the data element (see below), is there anything I can add to the - (void)parser: method, how might I do that?

```
<data version="1.0">2046 3433 5674 3422 4456 8990 1200 5284</data>
```

Here are sections of my code:

```
// CLASS:

@interface CustomParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
}
-(void)parseFile:(NSString *)pathToFile;
@end

@implementation CustomParser

-(void)parseFile:(NSString *)pathToFile {
    NSLog(@"parseXMLFile ... \"%@\"", pathToFile);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
    NSLog(@"Found: %@", string);
}
@end
```

.

```
//CALLED:
CustomParser *newParser = [[CustomParser alloc] init];
[newParser parseFile:fileOnDisk];

... more

[newParser release];
```

.

```
//DATA:
<!DOCTYPE tubinerotationdata>
<turbine version="1.0">
<status version="1.0" result="200">OK</status>
<data version="1.0">
    2046 3433 5674 3422 4456 8990 1200 5284
</data>
</turbine>
```

gary

Comment: I am guessing I will need to add an instance variable to track the current element, I am just not sure how to set that variable with the element/tag name that parser:foundCharacters: is processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [didStartElement](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-BBCIFIIG) and [didEndElement](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-BBCHIBFE) methods and use ivars to keep track of the current element name and value.

Example of one way to do it:

```
//Instance variables:  
NSString *currentElementValue;
NSString *statusValue;
NSString *dataValue;
```

In didStartElement:

```
currentElementValue = @"";
```

In foundCharacters:

```
currentElementValue = [currentElementValue stringByAppendingString:string];
```

in didEndElement:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"status"])
{
    statusValue = currentElementValue;
}
else
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"])
{
    dataValue = currentElementValue;
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a ivar that keeps track of the current element name and in foundCharacters set the statusValue and dataValue based on that.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try, but thats exactly what I was searching for. Much appreciated.